# How to return exist object if exist as cache?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following methos that can request server and returns data. In my case it returns data from object:

```
load(): Promise<TreeNode> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.hasPermission()) {
            resolve(cloneDeep(this.layersManager.commonLayers));
        }

        reject();
    });
}

How cache it and dont return clone if before it was?
```

I have tried this:

public loaded: Layer[];

```
if (this.hasPermission()) {
      if(!this.loaded.length) {
        this.loaded = cloneDeep(this.layersManager.commonLayers);
        resolve(this.loaded);
      } else {
           return this.loaded;
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
private _cachedPromise?: Promise<TreeNode>;

load(): Promise<TreeNode> {
    if (!this._cachedPromise) {
        this._cachedPromise = new Promise<TreeNode>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.hasPermission()) {
                resolve(cloneDeep(this.layersManager.commonLayers));
            }
            else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    }
    return this._cachedPromise;
}
```

This works because when the `then` method of a promise is called more than once, the function passed to `then` will always get the same value (the one with which the promise was resolved).